# How to setup gerrithub.io with github for a small group

Tags: git, gerrit

I want to setup gerrithub.io so that when we push changes, it needs at least one other reviewer to +2 it before it can merge.

I have created a new github repo, signed into gerrithub.io and had it import the repo. However, I have no idea what I need to do to get it to recognize 3 of us as contributors, review each others code on the project, and setup review rules. Can anyone explain the steps to perform this?

Answer (score 1):

Those steps should be in the [Project Owner Guide](https://review.gerrithub.io/Documentation/intro-project-owner.html).

They include:

- [Access Rights](https://review.gerrithub.io/Documentation/intro-project-owner.html#access-rights), which then refers to the [Gerrit Access Controls](https://review.gerrithub.io/Documentation/access-control.html) page,
- [Submit Rules](https://review.gerrithub.io/Documentation/intro-project-owner.html#submit-rules), with an example like "[Make change submittable only if Code-Review+2 is given by a non author](https://review.gerrithub.io/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#NonAuthorCodeReview)"